# Convert/Replace space with %20 and vice versa in c#

Tags: c#, package, uri

Below is the code to create a zip file and to add files to it.

> Problem: Currently, when the zip file is created, the files present in it contains `%20` instead of `space` which is one functionality.I have another requirement to replace `%20` with `space`. How to achieve this in below code.

Removed the code from the post.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example using the `Uri` static class:

```
var url = "http://www.somewhere.net/Thingy%20World.html";

var decoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url);
//decoded is currently 'http://www.somewhere.net/Thingy World.html'

var encoded = Uri.EscapeUriString(decoded);//back to encoded
//encoded is currently 'http://www.somewhere.net/Thingy%20World.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx

Unescaping data strings would be an easy way. You could also look into Regex and Regex.Replace.

Edit: Oh - and you can use EscapeDataString to place %20 into the string. As for the Regex approach, you could try
`Regex encodeSpace = new Regex(" "]);` and then you can call a replace on your string `string newStringWithNoSpaces = encodeSpace.Replace(oldString, "%20");` You can do something similar for the other direction.